# WordPress Toolset disable taxonomy input list not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to disable the input list which is normally shown on the create post taxonomy input when you enter a taxonomy which is already set to a post in WordPress:

[image]

I mean the dropdown which is really ugly and not useful for me. I've tried to set `autocomplete="off"` to the input but this has no effect. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution after some hours of work. Toolset created his own datalist autocomplete which gets generated during an input and gets removed when unfocusing the input field. So it's hard to analyze the HTML DOM because when you open the analyze window the input gets unfocused and the element get's remove. So do this and the suggestion is gone:

```
.wpt-suggest-taxonomy-term {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost at halfway to the solution.

1. Add `autocomplete="off"` onto `<form>` element;
2. Add hidden `<input>` with `autocomplete="false"` as a first children element of the form.

And it should work. Please give me feedback if it helped you.

Regards.